# Spectral properties of hypercyclic operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, invariant-subspace

I'm studying some topics related to the invariant subspace problem, and
consequently I find myself dealing with hypercyclic operators.

(An operator $T:X\rightarrow X$ is hypercyclic if there is some vector $x\in
X$ such that the set $\left\{ x,Tx,T^{2}x,...\right\}$ is dense in $X$, $x$ is then called a
hypercyclic vector)

So I'm trying to find references on spectral properties of these kind of
operators, and how it depends on the iterates of the hypercyclic vectors.

My first intuition is that the spectrum of a hypercyclic operator is always
connected, so if anyone can tell me something about this suspicion or any other related fact I will
be very grateful.

Thank you !

Comment: It is not true that the spectrum is always connected. For example, the "multiplication" operator over $\ell^2$ given by
$$
T[(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}] = (a_n x_n)
$$
will be hypercyclic whenever $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is a bounded, non-repeating sequence. The spectrum will consist of the elements $(a_n)$ together with any limit/cluster points.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you !

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What would be the hypercyclic vector in this case ?

Comment: Any vector with no zero-entries. For instance, the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n = 2^{-n}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Must $(a_{n})_{n}$ be in $l^{2}$ ?

Comment: No; $T$ will be bounded whenever $(a_n) \in \ell^\infty$. For instance, if $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, then we have the identity operator (which is certainly bounded).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom in fact I'm interested in the cluster points in the spectra of hypercyclic operators, is there any result about ?

Comment: I don't know of any results specific to hypercyclic operators except to those that extend from the finite dimensional case. A "diagonalizable" operator is cyclic/hypercyclic iff it has no repeating eigenvalues, and all eigenspaces of a hypercyclic operator must be one dimensional.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you so much

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the example you give is very interesting.
I have an other question please,
Must all the entries of $(a_{n})_{n}$ be nonzero ?

Comment: Not necessarily. As we've established, however, at most one of the elements $a_n$ is allowed to be zero.